# List custom taxonomy items per category

Tags: php, wordpress

I seek some help listing all post titles per custom taxonomy category. It's a taxonomy registered to native wordpress pages.

Please check below what I tried so far:

My Taxonomy adding code:

function create_topics_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

```
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'alltanks', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tank Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tank Categories' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Tank Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Tank Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tank Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tank Category' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Tank Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tank Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tank Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Tank Categories' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy('tanks',array('page'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true
    //'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tankcategory' ),
  ));

}
```

Query posts:

```
<?php
           $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post', // or should it be page?
            'posts_per_page' => '1',
            'order_by' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC', 
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'alltanks',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'cat' => 49
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
           ?>
           <?php if (have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: We have your config, your code, but we are still missing your question ;-)

Comment: The question is, what am I doing wrong to list all posts that belong to that specific category I am aiming. Category ID is 100% 49 I also tried using a slug but nothing worked. Maybe it's because it's a page and not post?

Comment: your query has multiple issues, it will only display 1 result and you are using "cat" instead of "terms".. see this for a good example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165610/get-posts-under-custom-taxonomy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - Getting posts in a custom taxonomy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322090/wordpress-getting-posts-in-a-custom-taxonomy)